# Сделать анимированный div по умолчанию открытым

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Всем привет!
Тут есть пример анимированного закрытия и открытия diva.

Как по умолчанию сделать его открытым?
http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/3/

Заранее Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держите http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/383/